# VB.NET insert a variable from code behind into aspx img src

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I'm trying to use a variable from my code behind as the src for an image.  Here is what I have, but it isn't working.

In my code behind at class level I have:

```
Dim maxImage As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("imgpath")
```

And in the aspx:

```
<img src="<%# maxImage %>" alt="mylisting" height="275" width="275">
```

If I just stick the value for maxImage in there the picture shows up, so for some reason the maxImage variable isn't getting inserted? I'm guessing my syntax is screwed up somehow and someone with more experience will be able to spot it right away.

When I "inspect element" in Chrome I get this:

```
<img src="" alt="mylisting" height="275" width="275">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `src="<%# maxImage %>"` with `src="<%= maxImage %>"`

Also make sure following line returns image path in correct format-

```
Dim maxImage As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("imgpath") 
// maxImage should be in format "../imagename.jpg"
```

Comment: Totally worked, thanks!  Although, after sleeping on it I think I should use javascript instead (faster)  Thank you, though... I knew it was something simple!